# Python: sorting list of lists not functioning as intended

Tags: python, list, sorting, lambda

I am trying to sort the following list of lists by the first item of each list in ascending order:

```
framenos = [
    ['1468', '2877', 'Pos.:', 95],
    ['3185', '4339', 'Pos.:', 96],
    ['195', '1460', 'Pos.:', 97]
]
```

I am using the following to do so:

```
framesorted = sorted(framenos, key=lambda x: x[0]) #sort ranges by start numbers
```

Which gives:

```
[['1468', '2877', 'Pos.:', 95], ['195', '1460', 'Pos.:', 97], ['3185', '4339', 'Pos.:', 96]]
```

What's going wrong?

Comment: Nothing is wrong. The result is what is expected from the line of code that you posted. Strings are sorted in lexical order, and so '1468' < '195' < '3185', since these are strings and not integers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your values are strings, so you are sorting [*lexicographically*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order), not numerically. `'1468'` is sorted before `'195'` because `'4'` comes before `'9'` in the ASCII standard, just like `'Ask'` would be sorted before `'Attribution'`.

Convert your strings to numbers if you need a numeric sort:

```
framesorted = sorted(framenos, key=lambda x: int(x[0]))
```

Demo:

```
>>> framenos = [
...     ['1468', '2877', 'Pos.:', 95],
...     ['3185', '4339', 'Pos.:', 96],
...     ['195', '1460', 'Pos.:', 97]
... ]
>>> sorted(framenos, key=lambda x: int(x[0]))
[['195', '1460', 'Pos.:', 97], ['1468', '2877', 'Pos.:', 95], ['3185', '4339', 'Pos.:', 96]]
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(_)
[['195', '1460', 'Pos.:', 97],
 ['1468', '2877', 'Pos.:', 95],
 ['3185', '4339', 'Pos.:', 96]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the first element of each list is a string, is is sorting these numbers in alphabetical order.  in order to sort these lists based on the integer value of the first element try casting to int:

```
framesorted = sorted(framenos, key=lambda x: int(x[0]))
```